# Persisting permissions on /mnt/shell after reboot

Tags: backup, file-system, dropbox, nandroid, file-permissions

CWM Nandroid backups are being stored in /mnt/shell/emulated/clockworkmod

I want to use DropSync (or something similar) to automatically upload the contents of this folder to Dropbox as a backup however the permissions on the /mnt/shell folder are 700 so DropSync isn't able to access them.

I can change the permissions to 755 which allows everything to work but as soon as I reboot the device the permissions reset to 700.

How can I persist the permissions? Or is there a better way of getting the backups automatically uploaded to Dropbox?